# set no menu / menubar | remove default menu [electronjs]

Tags: javascript, angular, menu, electron, menubar

I am using eletronjs for an angular app.

Because of the app design, which is also running in browser, I don't need/want to have the default or any electronjs menu/menubar.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the menu to `null` but if you're shipping your app for Mac this goes against the app guidelines. You should at least be including a basic menu on macOS.

This is how you ensure there is a minimal menu for mac:

```
    import { app, Menu } from 'electron';

    if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
      const template = [
        {
          label: app.getName(),
          submenu: [{ role: 'about' }, { type: 'separator' }, { role: 'hide' }, { role: 'hideothers' }, { role: 'unhide' }, { type: 'separator' }, { role: 'quit' }]
        },
        {
          label: 'Edit',
          submenu: [{ role: 'undo' }, { role: 'redo' }, { type: 'separator' }, { role: 'cut' }, { role: 'copy' }, { role: 'paste' }, { role: 'selectall' }]
        },
        {
          label: 'View',
          submenu: [{ role: 'togglefullscreen' }]
        },
        {
          role: 'window',
          submenu: [{ role: 'minimize' }, { role: 'close' }]
        }
      ];

      Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
    } else {
      Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)
    }
```